# Format Duration - Timer

Tags: front-end, formatação, dart, flutter

Estou tentando formatar em Dart/Flutter o timer de um determinado tempo decorrido, cujo código:

```dart
Duration _tempo = new Duration();

Text('Tempo: ${_tempo.inHours}:${_tempo.inMinutes}:${_tempo.inSeconds}'),
```

O resultado da linha acima é:

- **Tempo: 1:2:65**

Dizendo que já transcorreu uma hora, dois minutos e 5 segundos.

O resultado que eu preciso seria: `hh:nn:ss` (Hora - Minuto - Segundo) com dois dígitos pra cada, com os segundos zerando de 60 em 60, que no exemplo acima ficaria:

- **Tempo: 01:02:05**

Porém não consegui fazer isso, não encontrei nenhum material que me ajudasse nesse sentido, se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao utilizar os métodos inMinutes e inSeconds você está apenas retornando o valor total desse período de tempo em minutos e segundos respectivamente.

```dart
var d = Duration(hours: 1, minutes: 2, seconds: 65);
```

`d.inHours` -> **1**

`d.inMinutes` -> **63**

`d.inSeconds` -> **3785**

É necessário então uma simples operação matemática para converter esses valores em minutos e segundos, sendo simplismente a divisão do valor por 60, e recuperando o resto.

`inMinutes` -> 63 / 60 -> **Resto = 3**

`inSeconds` -> 3785 / 60 -> **Resto = 5**

O objeto `int` em dart tem um método que pega justamente esse resto da divisão, o [remainder()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/num/remainder.html).
Com isso basta um método utilitário que adicione um 0 a esquerda caso o valor for menor que 10:

```dart
void main() {
  Duration d = Duration(hours: 1, minutes: 2, seconds: 65); // 1:3:5

  print('${d.inHours}:${d.inMinutes}:${d.inSeconds}');
  // 1:63:3785

  int hour = d.inHours;
  int remainderMinutes = d.inMinutes.remainder(60);
  int remainderSeconds = d.inSeconds.remainder(60);
  print('${addZero(hour)}:${addZero(remainderMinutes)}:${addZero(remainderSeconds)}');
  // 01:03:05

  String sHour = hour.toString();
  String sRemainderMinutes = remainderMinutes.toString();
  String sRemainderSeconds = remainderSeconds.toString();
  print('${sHour.padLeft(2, '0')}:${sRemainderMinutes.padLeft(2, '0')}:${sRemainderSeconds.padLeft(2, '0')}');
  // 01:03:05
}

String addZero(int value) {
  return value < 10 ? "0$value" : "$value";
}
```

Uma outra alternativa mostrada no código acima, ao invés de usar o `addZero`, é converter o valor para String e utilizar justamente o método [padLeft()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/String/padLeft.html) que adiciona alguma outra String na esquerda da original caso a mesma seja menor que o tamanho passado.

[Teste no Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/44e4df1f83fd620bb10871c9bba8d960)

o/

Comment: Muito obrigado Júlio. Excelente!!! obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @Clarismilton se ajudou, coloque a resposta como correta/aceita :)

Comment: Não consegui colocar a resposta como correta/aceita... desculpe. mas não encontrei onde eu faço isso.

Comment: @Clarismilton basta clicar no símbolo de ✓ aqui na esquerda da pergunta (<===). Alterando de cinza para verde. Em caso de dúvida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ou https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079